# (Javascript) Problem with my if statement to make image larger again. Details:

Tags: javascript, if-statement, web, image-resizing

I am using Javascript and there is an image on my site that becomes larger when clicked on. I need an if statement that makes it smaller again when it’s clicked on again.

I am using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

0)Image is small
1)Image becomes large when clicked on
2)Image becomes smaller if clicked on again

I am having trouble with #2.

Here is my code:

```
if (thumbnailElement.className == "")
    {
    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
    thumbnailElement.className = "small"; });
    }
    else {
    thumbnail.Element.className=="";
     }
```

[image: picture of code in behavior. js file]

Comment: Please post your code as **text**, not as an image.

Comment: `thumbnailElement.className;` doesn't do anything. What is that line for?

Answer (score 0):

You should just have one event listener, it should contain the `if` statement that toggles the class.

But there's actually no need for an `if` statement, because there's a built-in method to toggle a class.

```js
thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  thumbnailElement.classList.toggle("small");
});
```

Comment: thank you so much!! the problem is I am required to use an if statement for this part!

Comment: Then see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById('smart_thumbnail')

thumbnailElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    if(thumbnailElement.classList.contains('small'))  {
        thumbnailElement.classList.remove("small");
        return
    }
    thumbnailElement.classList.add("small");
})})
```

If you really have to use 'if' statement